# how do we conclude restful api performance is good by using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, restful-url

I'm testing performance for restful API using Jmeter. So just I want to know that how could I verify its performance whether good or bad based on what type of validation & verification.

Answer (score 1):

Start with writing down your performance requirements. The requirements should cover both latency and throughput. For the sake of simplicity, suppose your API has only two operations: "read" and "write".

Your requirement might look like:

The API should support 10000 "read"s per second and 10000 "write"s per second, with a latency that is below 0.2 second in 90% of the cases.

Once you have this requirement described, try to simulate this scenario in JMeter, and see if the requirements are met.

Answer (score 1):

There is no criteria for "good" or "bad" performance. In general people are looking for the following answers:

- Is the system capable of serving anticipated number of users within reasonable response time
- In case of peak load how does the system behave?
- In case of stress load - what happens (data loss, processes shutdown, servers overloading/rebooting, etc.)? Does system recover when the load goes back to normal?
- What are bottlenecks and their causes (poor code quality, non-optimal configuration, network issues, etc.)?

Reference material:

- [Using SoapUI for load testing](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/load-testing.html)
- [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)